# Modification of Power Method

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

How to devise a simple modification of the power method to handle the following
case:
λ<sub>1</sub> = -λ<sub>2</sub> > |λ<sub>3</sub>| ≥ |λ<sub>4</sub>| ≥ |λ<sub>5</sub>| ≥ ... ≥ |λ<sub>n</sub>| ?

Could you please help me?

Comment: Devised, now what?

Comment: You asked a similar question on December 13, which was quickly closed for lack of context. This one will certainly meet a similar fate.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know the reason of that.

Comment: I have to agree the previous question wasn't formulated properly, yet i have problem with solving this task and im looking for tips or help with solving it therefore I have asked it in a more understandable way.

Comment: Since this is not a 'do my homework for free' service, you need to show the effort that you've made in attempting to solve this problem (or any other problem for that matter) on your own. In particularly if you're expecting others to make that effort for you.

Comment: I am not looking for the solution, but a hint for the approach which to take? Or is it that simple that such information would be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceed as usual in the theoretical exploration of the power method: Express the original vector and the dynamic of the power iteration in an eigenbasis of $A$.

$$
x=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3…\\
A^nx=c_1λ_1^nv_1+c_2(-λ_1)^nv_2+c_3λ_3^nv_3+…
$$

Comparing $A^nx$ and $A^{n+1}x$ should give you an idea or two.